# With Autofac is there a way to get the concrete type currently registered in a scope without resolving?

Tags: c#, autofac

#### Description

In Autofac, I have a registration.

```
var b = new ContainerBuilder();
b.RegisterType<BasicA>()
 .As<IBasicA>();
var container = b.Build()
```

Child scopes may override that registration.

I need to know in a child scope what Type would be resolved for when calling container.Resolve().

#### Bad Solution

Resolving gives me access to the type:

```
var type = scope.Resolve<IBasicA>().GetType();
```

#### Problem

*Resolving* is bad solution because it is a performance problem. I don't need to resolve IBasicA. I just need to know what concrete Type the current scope would use to resolve.

The concrete Type for IBasicA could be an AdvancedA, which could have hundreds of dependencies. The performance is terrible if Resolve is used to get the concrete Type.

#### Question

How would can I dynamically get the concrete type without resolving? Something like this:

```
var concreteType = scope.WhatTypeIsRegisteredFor<IBasicA>();
```

Comment: For what do you need to know the information which implementation is registered for a given interface?

Comment: This is kind of a tricky one to achieve in a 'general' sense, not least because of lambda registrations where the whole point is that the concrete type isn't even known until resolve time.

Comment: If it's just for reflection-based registrations (RegisterType), or some limited lambda situations, you should be able to go `container.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration` with a `TypedService` arg. That should give you the component registration with an `Activator` property.  That should have a `LimitType` property, which is the most accurate understanding we have of what type will be resolved. Not posting as an answer because I'm on phone so doing this off the top of my head.

Comment: @Progman I don't actually need to know the type. My code would be faster if it could know if the type implements interface IA or interface IAdvancedA. The problem is that I have to resolve the type (i.e instantiate it and all it's dependencies) to get the type to see if the type implements an interface. If I could check without resolving the code would work faster as I don't need to resolve at that point.